# How to associate RDG files to the RDC Manager shipped with sysinternals when sysinternals comes from the MS Store?

Tags: file-association, sysinternals, rdc-manager

I installed the sysinternals suite from the [Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P7KNL5RWT25).

This includes Microsoft Remote Desktop Manager.

However, this setup does not create file associations.

How to associate RDG files to this app ?

As a workaround, I selected manually `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SysinternalsSuite_1.1.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Tools\RDCMan.exe` as associated app, but I'm not sure if its reliable (because of the version number in the path).

Is there a proper way?

PS: working on W10 21H2 x64

Comment: I think you could make a general shortcut to RDCMan (say, on your desktop) and use that associate with. If the path to RDCMan should change, you update your shortcut and will keep working.

Comment: It may help to solve the version changes, but it still seems to be kind of hack.